# Create git branch, and revert original to upstream state

Tags: git, version-control, github

I recently screwed up my git repo and would like to find out if there is any remedy to it.

My setup is this:

```
Central repo on github.
Personal repo on github (which is a fork of Central)
   +Central is setup as remote (upstream/master)
   +Master branch (origin/master)
   +Feature branch (origin/feature)
```

My workflow was like this:

```
Need to fix something in Central:
   1. checkout Master
   2. Make changes
   3. Pull from upstream/master and merge
   3. Commit, push to upstream/master

Need to work on a New Feature:
   1. Checkout/Create Feature branch
   2. Work work work
   3. Pull from upstream/master and merge
   4. Commit, push to upstream/master
```

This way I always had a pristine state of Central in my Master branch.

Now what I did was started working on Master branch instead. So I made changes to my master and can no longer branch from it to get a copy of Central. Whenever I need to make and push some fixes to Central, i have to clone the Central into another directory and work from there.

My question: Is there a way to "revert" my master to be an identical copy of the Central, while moving all the changes I have made on my Master into another branch (say Feature)?

I know it's confusing, and I would appreciate any help. I will clarify if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well the solution was pretty simple, hinted by Pat Notz and Bombe.

```
#Make sure we're on the master branch
$ git checkout master

# Make a new branch to hold the work I've done
$ git branch old_master

# Save this branch on my remote repo (for backup)
$ git checkout old_master
$ git push origin old_master

# Reset my local master back to match the commit just before I started 
# working on my new feature
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard 2aa93842342342

# Get it to be the same as my Central
$ git pull upstream master

# Now DELETE my master on my remote repo
$ git push origin :master

# And recreate it
$ git push origin master

# Branch created!
#* [new branch]      master -> master

#
```

Now I have two nice branches: master and old_master. With master being a copy of my Central, for fixes to production, and old_master holding all the work that I did previously!

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for following up with your solution.  I was just trying to sort out your situation -- glad you figured it out.

Comment: I think instead of your 4th command there, "git push old_master origin old_master", you should have "git push origin old_master"? I'm hoping that's right, because that's what seemed to work for me. Otherwise I got an error message: "fatal: 'old_master' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: I could not "git push origin :master". This post explains a way of dealing with that. http://matthew-brett.github.com/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html The key is, make sure master is not the default branch on github. A good policy if you are working on a forked repo.

Comment: Or if you have ssh/command line access to the bare repo you can issue this command from the bare repo directory `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/old_master`, then delete, then switch symbolic-ref back to master: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468322/switch-current-branch-in-git-bare-repository

Answer (score 16):

```
# Make sure we're on the master branch
$ git checkout master

# Make a new branch to hold the work I've done
$ git branch old_master

# Reset my local master back to match origin/master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now you can checkout `old_master` and use it just like you did your `feature` branch

Comment: Origin/master refers to the remote repository of my Master. But I already PUSHED my changes to my github repo.
What I need to to is reset it to upstream/master where my Central repo is. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, `git reset --hard upstream/master` seems to work fine (if you've set upstream to point at the correct repo).

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you mean by

> I messed [up] my master and can no longer branch from it.

You can always create a new branch from any commit in your repository, no matter how “messed up” it may be–which by the way is something Git has no notion of.

Basically you can revert your repository to any state it previously had because Git will not explicitely delete any objects, it will only garbage collect unreferenced (dangling) objects every now and then. So you just need to find out what your repository looked like. `gitk` or `git log` can help you there.

After you restored your local repository to a state you like you can simply push it back to your central public repository. If that results in a non-fast-forward push you might need to specify the `--force` flag when pushing.

Comment: Hi, I meant that I can no longer branch from it to get a copy of the Central repo, so I can start working on a new feature.
Regarding your suggestion, I thought of that - but that will cause me to loose all my work I did on my master. Will it not? Thanks.