# Switch current branch in git bare repository

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I actually want to remove a branch in the bare repository i am working with, but this task hits a dead end because I cannot switch away from the master repository without a 'work tree' which a bare repository does not have.

When I run `git branch -d master` the output is:

```
error: Cannot delete the branch 'master' which you are currently on.
```

So I try to switch to another branch called 'develop' by running `git checkout develop` and the output is:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3301956/4918, but is exactly my use-case and much better to read. Thus I +1 here and do not flag, just link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try this instead of `git checkout`:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/develop
```

Then you should be able to delete master.

Comment: `git clone --bare` does not create a `refs/heads/master`. Short of editing `HEAD` manually, how do I switch the symbolic ref for `HEAD` back to `master` if no such head exists?

Comment: @dimadima The same way.  If you look in `packed-refs` you should see that it contains a definition for `refs/heads/master`.

Comment: See also this answer by @VonC explaining about [symbolic-ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository#3302018).