# Need to reset git branch to origin version

Tags: git

I was accidentally working on a branch I shouldn't have been for a while, so I branched off of it giving it the appropriate name.  Now I want to overwrite the branch I shouldn't have been on to the version from origin (github).  Is there an easy way to do this?  I tried deleting the branch and then resetting up the tracking branch, but it just gives me the version I was working on again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)

Comment: With Git 2.23 (August 2019): `git switch -C mybranch origin/mybranch`. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302259/6309)

Answer (score 1306, accepted):

If you haven't pushed to origin yet, you can reset your branch to the [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166) branch with:

```
git checkout mybranch
git reset --hard origin/mybranch
```

(Make sure that you reference your latest commit in a separate branch, like you mention in your question)

Note that just after the reset, `mybranch@{1}` refers to the old commit, before reset.

But if you had already pushed, see "[Create git branch, and revert original to upstream state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/773728/6309)" for other options.

---

With **Git 2.23 (August 2019)**, that would be one command: [**`git switch`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).
Namely: [`git switch -C mybranch origin/mybranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--Cltnew-branchgt)

Example

```
C:\Users\vonc\git\git>git switch -C master origin/master
Reset branch 'master'
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

That restores the index and working tree, like a `git reset --hard` would.

---

As commented by [Brad Herman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259628/brad-herman), a `reset --hard` would **remove any new file or reset modified file to HEAD**.

Actually, to be sure you start from a "clean slate", a `git clean -f -d` after the reset would ensure a working tree *exactly* identical to the branch you just reset to.

---

This [blog post](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/git/reset-and-sync-local-respository-with-remote-branch/) suggests those aliases (for `master` branch only, but you can adapt/extend those):

> ```
> [alias]
>    resetorigin = !git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master && git clean -f -d
>    resetupstream = !git fetch upstream && git reset --hard upstream/master && git clean -f -d
> ```
>
> Then you can type:
>
> ```
> git resetupstream
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> git resetorigin
> ```

Comment: this will DELETE UNSTAGED/STAGED changes (from the --hard)

Comment: I have used the `git reset --hard origin/mybranch` command several times when I didn't care about any local changes and just wanted a clean copy that matched the origin.  However, today, this didn't work -- I still had a handful of new, unstaged files, and git kept promising me that it was at HEAD.  The note about `git clean -f -d` fixed that by wiping up all the new files that I didn't want.

Comment: @MatthewClark That is expected: see comment on http://stackoverflow.com/q/4327708/6309

Comment: Great! Also many times i have used `git reset --hard HEAD` to revert to a previous commit, ignoring any changes

Comment: Is this possible with sourctree, too?

Comment: @Lonzak Yes: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/Reset-Head-in-Source-Tree/qaq-p/366466#M10933. Don't select the soft option. See also https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/how-should-i-remove-push-commit-from-sourcetree/qaq-p/299176#M31721 for an illustration.

Answer (score 113):

There is a slightly easier way to do this:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

`@{u}` is a shortcut for whatever your tracking branch is, so if you're on `master` and that tracks `origin/master`, `@{u}` points to `origin/master`.

The advantage of using this is that you don't have to remember (or type out) the full name of your tracking branch. You can also make an alias:

```
git-reset-origin="git reset --hard @{u}"
```

which will work regardless of the branch you're currently on.

Comment: Note, in powershell you need to escape `{u}` so the full command will be something like `git reset --hard "@{u}"`

Comment: Thanks for this! Now that I learned it exists, I found it is documented in https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Comment: It is a piece of cake, saved by time today, thanks  @andy lei

Comment: This ought to be marked as the solution. So much simpler.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. BTW `@{u}` is a shorthand for `@{upstream}`

Answer (score 36):

Assuming this is what happened:

```
# on branch master
vi buggy.py                 # you edit file
git add buggy.py            # stage file
git commit -m "Fix the bug" # commit
vi tests.py                 # edit another file but do not commit yet
```

Then you realise you make changes on the wrong branch.

```
git checkout -b mybranch    # you create the correct branch and switch to it
```

But `master` still points to your commit. You want it to point where it pointed before.

### Solution

The easiest way is:

```
git branch --force master origin/master
```

Another way is:

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft origin/master
git checkout mybranch
```

Note that using `reset --hard` will cause your uncommitted changes to be lost (`tests.py` in my example).

Answer (score 16):

I tried this and it didn't reset my current branch to my remote github latest.
I googled and found 
https://itsyndicate.org/blog/how-to-use-git-force-pull-properly/

which suggested

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I wanted to reset my v8 branch so I did

```
git fetch origin v8
git reset --hard origin/v8
```

and it worked

Answer (score 11):

I have a private repo on a server and regularly rebase/force-push to it, which makes it necessary to reset the local branch on my other computer often. I therefore created the following alias "catchup", which allows doing this for the current branch. Unlike the other answer there is no hardcoded branch name in this alias.

Hold on tight.

```
[alias]
  catchup = "!f(){ echo -n \"reset \\033[0;33m$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)\\033[0m to \\033[0;33m$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD))\\033[0m? (Y/n) \"; read -r ans; if [ \"$ans\" = \"y\" -o \"$ans\" = \"Y\" -o -z \"$ans\" ]; then git reset --hard $(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)); else echo \"catchup aborted\"; fi }; f"
```

Properly formatted (won't work with the newlines in .gitconfig) it looks like this:

```
"
!f(){
  echo -n \"reset \\033[0;33m$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)\\033[0m to \\033[0;33m$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD))\\033[0m? (Y/n) \";
  read -r ans;
  if [ \"$ans\" = \"y\" -o \"$ans\" = \"Y\" -o -z \"$ans\" ]; then
    git reset --hard $(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD));
  else
    echo \"catchup aborted\";
  fi
}; f
"
```

- The `\\033[0;33m` and `\\033[0m` is for emphasizing the current branch and upstream with color.
- `$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)` is the current branch name
- `$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD))` is the upstream of the current branch.

Since reset is a potentially dangerous call (especially with the --hard option, you will lose any uncommitted changes), it first tells you what it's about to do. For example if you're on branch *dev-container* with remote called *qcpp/dev-container* and you enter `git catchup`, you'll be prompted:

> reset dev-container to qcpp/dev-container? (Y/n)

If you then type y or just hit return, it will perform the reset. If you enter anything else the reset will not be carried out.

If you want to be super safe and programmatically prevent losing unstaged/uncommitted changes, you can pimp the above alias further with [according checks for diff-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommited-changes).

The obligatory word of warning: If you are working on a public repository other people have based work on, and you need this alias, [you are doing it wrong™](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing).