# Update a pull request using a separate branch

Tags: git, pull-request

I was searching a lot for the proper solution but I didnt find anything similar.

I have a branch which I was working and a pull request of that. I needed to make another branch to cherry-pick some of the commits. But this branch is from another backup branch of the first branch. My question is how to update the existing pull request which I used for far?

Any additional info about is welcome and will be helpful.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The pull request is on a branch on the remote repo:

- fetch that repo
- make a `tmp` branch on top of your current branch
- [reset your current branch to `origin/theBranchOfThePullRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302259/6309)
- cherry-pick your commit in that reset branch
- push it back (that will update the pull request automatically)

Comment: What I ask is about the last step. To make it clear I have already a tmp(lets say new_tmp) branch but not by the original branch but by another tmp/backup branch. I wonder if i give a commit --amend and a push will do it automatically or if it will push the new_tmp branch itself. Notice that the new_tmp is cloned by tmp. Does this make any different for the existing pr. I need to update the existing pr with the new_tmp branch.

Comment: @b10n1k as long as you are pushing to the `pr` branch (`push` or `push --force` after a `git commit --amend`), that will update the PR automatically.

Comment: Ok I did a git commit --amend and a git push -f myremote new_tmp but the pr did not update automatically. Instead, now i see a new "compare & pull request" on github.

Comment: @b10n1k did you push it to the branch where the pr already exist? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309

Comment: i pushed using git push -f myremote myremote/branch_with_ex_pr. it doesnt work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @b10n1k why repeating `myremote`? It should be `git push -f myremote branch_with_ex_pr`