# How to clean up my Git history

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm still quite new to Git but have thus far been able to figure out how to do what I want to do with some searching. I'm trying to clean up my Git history and remove a previous commit and branch called `bootstrap-v4` but haven't had any luck so far. Can someone suggest how to remove the branch and extra commit and keep my `master` branch clean?

[image: My current Git history]

Comment: Tl;Dr you don't GIT doesn't work like that. A branch is just a pointer on the graph. You can delete the branch (pointer) but all the commits and where they sit remain in the graph

Comment: Is there a way to roll back the history then and remake the changes? Maybe it's a little OCD but it bothers me having redundant commits or branches that I don't need. I know there are ways to append and change commits to help clean things up.

Comment: I think what your saying is when you did the merge you should of done a [fast forward merge](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-achieve-fast-forward-merge-in-SourceTree/qaq-p/99606). FYI having used several GIT UIs I don't rate source tree. It looks fancy but IMO it's functionality is confusing. If your starting out I'd give [GIT extensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) (no affiliation) a go instead. It makes this kind of thing much easier (or better yet learn the GIT command line interface)

Comment: *Is there a way to roll back the history* Yes, [use `git reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301782/need-to-reset-git-branch-to-origin-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GUI is showing you your uncommitted changes, which is the merge of `bootstrap-v4` branch to `master`. If you do not wish to commit those changes, that is what a `git reset --hard origin/master` would accomplish (alas, I am not familiar with the operation of your GUI, but it should offer you some way of doing a hard reset)

As for removing the remote branch, on the command line, it would be: `git push origin :bootstrap-v4`

Comment: Thanks Ben, that did the trick! I'm not sure if there was a way to do it in SourceTree but I opted for using `Terminal`. Cheers.