# How can I remove all local git branches and clone all new?

Tags: git, github

I am having issues with `git` on my local machine. I would like to delete all branches on my machine and start all over again by cloning the project from git.

Note: that I don't want to delete the branches on GitHub.com. Delete locally only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to reset git branch to origin version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301782/need-to-reset-git-branch-to-origin-version)

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) rename your current project `myproject.bu`, then 2) git clone` into a brand new directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're ok with losing all work that you've done locally, you can simply delete the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Several alternatives:

1. Save a backup of your local work, and go back to the Github version:

   - Rename your current project directory and re-clone from Github.
2. Undo all your local changes, and go back to the last local commit:

   - `git reset --hard HEAD`
3. Reset your local project to the Github version:

   - [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/)

     ```
     git fetch origin
     git reset --hard origin/master
     git clean -f
     ```

It depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.