# Git: Safely moving my (unpushed) commits to a different branch?

Tags: git

I recently did a freelance assignment from the master branch of my customer's project by mistake. I assured him that I could move my work to an entirely different branch and return master to the original commit I started from.

I already checked out a new branch (via `git checkout -b NewBranch`)
But between `reset` `revert` and `cherry-pick` it's not clear to me which command best suits my needs.

Specifically, I want to make it look like the master branch was never touched. I'm afraid of rolling back to a previous commit on `master` and losing the commits on `NewBranch`
Note: none of my commits have been pushed

Comment: As long as the code has been committed you will have little reason to worry about data loss. If you're worried you can create "backup branches' which will prevent the commit from being deleted by accident (which is already very unlikely).

Comment: Just reset your local master to orgin’s master. Sounds like you’re newBranch is good to go.

Comment: Yup, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard/59675191?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.8176#59675191. This is regret Type 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to reset git branch to origin version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301782/need-to-reset-git-branch-to-origin-version)

Comment: Confused. Did you push to `master` or not? The title suggest no but the body suggests yes

Comment: @matt that explanation is gold. i appreciate all the replies