# Reset local branch (master) to the state of the remote branch (master)

Tags: git

I have some old local commits in the local master, so `git status` shows that I' ahead of origin/master by 58 commits. I don't care about those old commits and would like to reset the local master to be current with the remote master. What's the preferred to do that? Ditto for another branch.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen, thanks, it answered the question, modified as in eftshift0's answer below. I should have found it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you don't care about anything in your current branch, then the simplest is to `reset --hard`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This forces your local master to be like origin/master, in content and history. Use with care... anything in the working tree that is not committed will be set the way it is in origin/master.

Answer (score 1):

In one command, since Git 2.23, using [`git switch -C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--Cltnew-branchgt):

```
git switch -C master origin/master
```

> This is a convenient shortcut for:
>
> ```sh
> $ git branch -f <new-branch>
> $ git switch <new-branch>
> ```

As I explained in "[Need to reset git branch to origin version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302259/6309)", you would still need a `git clean -f -d` to make sure any *new and unstaged* files are also removed (they would not be by a `reset`/`switch -C` alone).

Make sure to do a `git clean -n -d` first though, to get a *preview* of what would be removed that was.

Comment: This is cool, and worked great!