# How can I reset to the main branch in git

Tags: git, git-reset

I want to make my current branch exactly the same as my main branch. When I do 'git reset --hard main', it does the job. But then when I push it complains that it is behind.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.bol.io/sequoia/relevanc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried using logs but it doesn't work... just want to go back to the main branch... how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to reset git branch to origin version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301782/need-to-reset-git-branch-to-origin-version)

Comment: What does "exactly the same as the main branch" mean? If they are to be _exactly_ the same, you would just move your branch pointer to main so that they are the _same commit_. But then what is your branch even for? You might as well just delete your branch, since main already exists.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: I ended up removing my branch and making a new branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A branch in Git is merely a name for a commit. That's just about all it is. So the phrase "make my current branch exactly the same as my main branch" is ambiguous. What is it supposed to mean?

Let's say you have this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D <- main
      \
       X -- Y -- Z <- mybranch
```

When you say you want `mybranch` to be the same as `main`, you might mean one of two things (at least).

#### Possibility 1

You might mean: "I don't care about Z. I don't care about Y. I don't care about X. I'm sorry I ever made them. I'm sorry about all the work I've done on `mybranch`. I want `mybranch` to start all over, emanating from where `main` is now."

Then there is no need for all this violence (hard reset, force push, etc.). Just delete `mybranch` altogether! It serves no purpose:

```
git fetch
git switch --det origin/main
git branch -D mybranch
git push origin --delete mybranch
```

Now `mybranch` is gone — both locally and on the remote. If you now want to start over, with `mybranch` emanating from `main`, then start over: make `mybranch`:

```
git switch -c mybranch
git push origin mybranch
```

Result on the remote:

```
A -- B -- C -- D <- main, mybranch
```

As you can see, `main` and `mybranch` are the same commit, and the separate history of `mybranch` is effectively gone.

#### Possibility 2

You might mean: I want to keep X and Y and Z but I want the state of my project in `mybranch` to be identical to the state of my project in `main`.

Then you would reverse merge `mybranch` into `main` with the `ours` strategy, and then merge `main` into `mybranch`:

```
git fetch
git switch --det origin/main
git merge -s ours mybranch
git switch mybranch
git merge origin/main
git push origin mybranch
```

Result on the remote:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- M (identical to D) <- main, mybranch
      \            /
       X -- Y -- Z
```

As you can see, `main` and `mybranch` now point to the same commit, M, which is identical (in content) to D, which was the state of `main`; but the *history* has been *preserved*.

Comment: Seems like you understood it enough to answer it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make my current branch exactly the same as my main branch.

```bash
$ git checkout <branchname>
$ git fetch origin/main
$ git reset --hard origin/main
$ git push --force-with-lease origin <branchname>
```

this will set the branch HEAD to the latest commit on the remote main branch. As you are rewriting the history of the branch, you will need to force push the branch (`--force-with-lease`) next time you push to the remote branch.

Comment: @Charles oh yeah of course, fixed

Comment: Thanks. I did it... but when I now do git push I get:
fatal: The current branch XXXX has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin XXXX

But when I do so, it says 
'fatal: XXXX cannot be resolved to branch'

Comment: @Charles there was a typo in the `git push` command

Comment: This is dangerous! A force push shouldn't be necessary if the local branch has been reset to the remote branch! If this is necessary you have differences and you should evaluate the status of your local and origin.

Comment: @kapsiR perhaps you didn't read the question carefully

Comment: Perhaps the original question is incomprehensible.

Comment: @matt I don't think so... ? its a fairly common question

Comment: Then find another such case and vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @matt well which one is it mate, is it incomprehensible or is it a duplicate?